# Fruit yogurt tastes chalky

Tags: yogurt

I made an experiment today making mango yogurt by adding mango puree BEFORE incubation. I used canned mango, pureed and strained it to eliminate fibers. I also added in the mixture condensed milk and powdered milk to increase protein. My yogurt was firm, thick and sour with mango flavor but it tasted chalky.

I'm not sure it was due to mango or powdered milk since I haven't used powdered milk in making yogurt as well and I added a quite large amount of it?

One more thing, I used skimmed milk without lactose and plain yogurt as culture.

Comment: "Tastes chalky" is a somewhat broad description. Was the problem the texture, or the aroma, or just a generally perceived "dryness" without the texture feeling actually gritty?

Comment: The texture was not creamy and smooth as usual but it was actually similar to apple puree but a bit thicker...  (it's hard for me to describe!)